# how to merge two columns to one column with the repeating word on column2 as a header

Tags: bash

i've been trying to figure this for a couple of hours now, here's what i need

my table:

```
 - 161.226.252.55           NY
 - 171.226.252.60           NY
 - 131.226.252.50           NY
 - 150.178.157.16           LA
 - 162.163.137.23           LA
 - 142.163.137.27           WY
 - 182.163.137.22           NL
```

desired output:

```
 - NY
 - 161.226.252.55
 - 171.226.252.60
 - 131.226.252.50
 - LA
 - 150.178.157.16 
 - and so on...
```

sorry for the bad format, it's my first question, thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i tried various grep/sort/gawk/awk, the list is great, i'm stuck in the part that brings the duplicate word from column 2 and sorts beneath it the matching rows

Comment: Please **show us your code**, if you would like assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWK solution using associative array:

```
awk '{ ips[$2]=ips[$2] $1 RS; } END { for ( i in ips ) printf("%s%s%s",i,RS,ips[i]); }' table
```

Output:

```
WY
142.163.137.27
NL
182.163.137.22
LA
150.178.157.16
162.163.137.23
NY
161.226.252.55
171.226.252.60
131.226.252.50
```

In case You need order as in Your provided output:

```
awk '!ips[$2] { ipso[++order]=$2; } { ips[$2]=ips[$2] $1 RS; } END { for (i=1;i<=order;i++) printf("%s%s%s",ipso[i],RS,ips[ipso[i]]); }' table
```

Output:

```
NY
161.226.252.55
171.226.252.60
131.226.252.50
LA
150.178.157.16
162.163.137.23
WY
142.163.137.27
NL
182.163.137.22
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, it worked. my bad but i forgot to mention that my columns has titles, and it shows up above the location, how can i remove them and only them?

Comment: in case you have one header just add condition NR>1. Like: awk ' NR>1 { ips[$2]=ips[$2] $1 RS; } END { for ( i in ips ) printf("%s%s%s",i,RS,ips[i]); }' table_headers

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried gawk/awk, you can create an array, in fact, a hashtable in awk, the key is your 2nd column. The values are those ips. When you put value in it, you check if there is value with that key, if true, append to the existing value. Finally, you can loop through the array, print the keys and values out, it should be in your desired format.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21486639)

Comment: @hivert this is not a comment. it is exactly an answer to the question, even if it doesn't contain any codes. It explains `how to merge two columns to one column with the repeating word on column2 as a header`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, it will give you output in same order in which ids are present in Input_file then try following.

```
awk '
!a[$NF]++{
  b[++count]=$NF
}
{
  c[$NF]=c[$NF]?c[$NF] ORS $1:$1
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
     print b[i] ORS c[b[i]]
  }
}'   Input_file
```